# Unity: How to resize a game object for a certain amount of time?

Tags: unity, scale, coroutines

I've tried to make a coroutine like this

```
private IEnumerator applyPowerUp(string type, GameObject player)
{
    GameObject originPlayer = new GameObject();
    originPlayer = player;

    if (type == "Bigger")
    {
        Debug.Log("make it big");
        player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.25f, 2.9f, 0);
        player.transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x + 0.4f, player.transform.position.y);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        player = originPlayer;
    }
}
```

The game object are getting bigger but after 5 secs it didn't turn back to its origin size.

Comment: Have you considered using [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/)? It is imo the best tweening lib for unity.

Comment: @Sidar I'll try that, thx for the info

Answer (score 2):

```
GameObject originPlayer = new GameObject();
originPlayer = player;
```

this doesn't do what you think it does.

instead you want to save the just the original scale and restore that:

```
if (type == "Bigger")
{
    Vector3 origScale = player.transform.localScale;

    Debug.Log("make it big");
    player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.25f, 2.9f, 0);
    player.transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x + 0.4f, player.transform.position.y);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    player.transform.localScale = origScale;
    player.transform.position = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x - 0.4f, player.transform.position.y);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but it didn't solve the problem, the scale still didn't back to the previous one. So, I try to assign the localScale with new Vector2 with the value same as the previous scale and it worked. Thx anyway.